# AttributeError: 'Application' object has no attribute 'label'

Tags: python, tkinter, attributeerror

My code gives this error someone can help me. When I place label to the rand_num() or tool() it doesn't matter it gives same error.
How can give attribute to label?

```
from tkinter import *
import random

class Application(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.rand_num()
    self.tool()

def tool(self):
    self.label = Label(fg="white", bg="#61380B", font="Helvetica 12 bold")
    self.label["text"] = self.list

    self.label.pack()
    self.open = Button(text='Hit', command=self.rand_num())
    self.open.pack()
    self.ok = Button(text='Exit', command=root.quit)
    self.ok.pack()

def rand_num(self):
    self.list = []
    for i in range(6):
        rand = random.randint(1, 49)
        if rand not in self.list:
            self.list.append(rand)
    self.list.sort()
    self.label["text"] = self.list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('300x100+500+100')
    app = Application()
    mainloop()
```

edit: I edited like this and work so well!

```
from tkinter import *
import random


class Application(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.tool() #Deleted that line

def rand_num(self):
    self.list = []
    for i in range(6):
        rand = random.randint(1, 49)
        if rand not in self.list:
            self.list.append(rand)
    self.list.sort()
    self.label["text"] = self.list

def tool(self):
    self.label = Label(text='Please enter hit', #Added 'text' attribute
                       fg="white",
                       bg="#61380B",
                       font="Helvetica 12 bold")
    #Deleted that line

    self.label.pack()
    self.open = Button(text='Hit', command=self.rand_num)
    self.open.pack()
    #self.ok = Button(text='Exit', command=root.quit)
    #self.ok.pack()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('300x100+500+100')
    app = Application()
    mainloop()
```

Changed parts are above
AttributeError: 'Application' object has no attribute 'label'

Answer (score 1):

You define `self.label` in the `tool()` method. The error is probably occuring because you call the `rand_num()` method before the `tool()` method.